# Could we actually freeze a star?

Tags: star, brown-dwarf

I read an article recently that said NASA has discovered a brown dwarf that has frozen. 
If we had the technology, resources, and supplies, could we actually freeze a star and stop it from burning its fuels? If so, how would we do it?

Comment: Brown dwarf is by definition not frozen.

Comment: Perhaps adding a reference to the article making these claims would help clarify the question.

Comment: Brown dwarfs also are not true stars.

Comment: Are you referring to [WISE J085510.83–071442.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISE_0855%E2%80%930714)?

Comment: @HDE226868 It'd be fun to seed one of those coolish dwarfs with some variety of hydrogen oxidizing bacteria http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC184866/ wait a billion years, and see what develops.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Wow. Think government funding would last that long?

Comment: @HDE226868 Embezzle a couple dollars from the NIH startup grant. Put it in an interest bearing savings account. Wait. -> Plenty of funds for followup study even if the government falls.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd somehow be able to freeze a star and stop nucleosynthesis (fusion) then it would not be a star anymore. By definition, a star needs a temperature high enough to support fusion. This is why brown dwarfs are not true stars.

There are of course stellar remnants (white dwarfs, neutron stars) that have actually crystallised (and are therefore in a solid state). See for instance [PSR J2222-0137](http://www.universetoday.com/112769/an-earth-sized-diamond-in-the-sky-the-coolest-known-white-dwarf-detected/). One might say they have 'frozen'.

How you might actually do that artificially, I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this [brown dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf) is so cold compared to other stars is that it *was never on the [main sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_sequence)*. More specifically, it never reached the hydrogen-1-burning phase of its life. Most stars (including our Sun) fuse elements together (beginning with hydrogen-1), which generates [heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star#Temperature). Brown dwarfs do not do this, and thus are much colder than other stars - although, as caters pointed out, some of the more massive ones *can* fuse deuterium, and possibly lithium.

So that brown dwarf is cold because it was never "hot" in the first place. I highly doubt that we could ever "freeze" a main sequence star, however, because we would have to somehow halt nuclear fusion.

Comment: They do actually fuse deuterium and lithium

Comment: @cater I meant to imply hydrogen-1, but evidently I was unclear. Thanks for pointing that out; edit on the way.

Comment: If we were to get a little hydrogen into its solid state and somehow put it on the star than I bet that the rest of the hydrogen will freeze before that little bit becomes plasma, especially if it is put on the relatively cool surface of the star. This would stop nuclear fusion in the star  and we would have left solid hydrogen and helium gas.

Comment: @caters How could you keep hydrogen that cold and still get it on the star in that state?